# Count and check if number of a string repetition in a Line is more than 1

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to count the number of occurrence of "1260005113" and then check if it is more than 1 or not

I am trying to count the number of occurrence of "1260005113" in the below log file.

```
1260005722,1000239103,1260005113,1000235906,1260004267,1260004642,1260005113,1260003996,1000239447,1000233697
1260005113,1260004642,1260004267,1260005722,1260003996
1000120365,1260005113,1260005113,1260005722,1000239103,1000239447,1260003996,1260004267,1000235906,1000233697
1000213089,1000154578,1000053838,1770003314
1000228336,1260005113,1000223808,1000225189,1260003996,1260004642,1000228200,1260005722,1260004267
1000228200,1000223808,1260005113,1260005722,1260004267,1000225189,1260003996,1260005113,1000228336
1000120365,1000233697,1260004642,1260005113,1000239103,1260005722,1260003996,1260004267,1000235906,1000239447
1000235906,1260004642,1260004267,1260003996,1000233697,1260005722,1000239103,1260005113,1000120365,1000239447
1260005722,1000239447,1000233697,1260003996,1000239103,1260004642,1000120365,1260005113,1000235906,1260004267
1000213089,1000154578,1000053838,1770003314
1000120365,1260005113,1260004642,1000235906,1000239103,1000239447,1000233697,1260005722,1260003996,1260004267
1260004267,1000233697,1000239103,1000235906,1260005722,1000120365,1260005113,1260004642,1000239447,1260003996
1260005722,1260004267,1000120365,1260003996,1000239447,1000235906,1260005113,1260004642,1000233697,1000239103
1260004267,1000239103,1000120365,1000235906,1000233697,1260005113,1000239447,1260004642,1260003996,1260005722
1000228336,1260005722,1260004267,1000225189,1260005113,1260004642,1260003996,1000228200,1000223808
1000233697,1260005722,1000235906,1000239447,1000120365,1260004267,1000239103,1260003996,1260004642,1260005113
1000213089,1000154578,1000053838,1770003314
1000120365,1000239103,1260003996,1260005722,1000235906,1260004642,1000239447,1260005113,1260004267,1000233697
```

i have used `awk -F '1260005113' '{print (NF?NF-1:0)}'`
and it gives me number of occurances of '1260005113'..

but i am unable to find how i can get only those line which have occurances of '1260005113' is more than 1.

so i only want to get lines 1,3, 5 which  have more the 1 repetition of 1260005113

Comment: ITYM "want to get lines 1,3, **6**", not 1, 3, 5.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F '1260005113' 'NF>2' file
1260005722,1000239103,1260005113,1000235906,1260004267,1260004642,1260005113,1260003996,1000239447,1000233697
1000120365,1260005113,1260005113,1260005722,1000239103,1000239447,1260003996,1260004267,1000235906,1000233697
1000228200,1000223808,1260005113,1260005722,1260004267,1000225189,1260003996,1260005113,1000228336
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'gsub(/1260005113/,"&")>1' file
```

`gsub(/1260005113/,"&")` replaces all `1260005113` with itself and returns the number of replacements took place, so basically it returns the number of occurences of `1260005113` in current line.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'gsub("1260005113","&")>1' Input_file
```

Above will catch `126000511312` too, so try more robust code which will catch only `1260005113` in fields.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="1260005113"){++count}};if(count>1){print};count=""}'  Input_file
```

Comment: You could put field anchors like `(^|,)` and `(,|$)` in the `gsub` regex just as well.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` (remember and check first match)

```
sed -rn '/(1260005113).*\1/p' logfile
```